# Unable to select custom Lightning Community page

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-community, community-builder

I have created a login component in LWC and added it in a Standard Page in lightning community. But I am unable to refer that login page from the login page type on the Login & Registration (L&R) page of the Administration workspace.

Login & Registration -> Login Page Type (Community Builder Page) -> unable to see my custom login page.

Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: Didyou give guest user access to the login page you created?

Comment: Yes Page Access set as Public

Comment: @Avijit on which standard page did you add the LWC component ?

Comment: I am creating from community builder Pages->new page->standard page

Comment: Each community has site auto created. Is the login page added to the site? @Avijit

Comment: Its lightning community page, do you think is there any way to add it under site?

Answer (score 3):

You have to change Meta file of the component to use in Lightning Community.

You Have to set the target for that.

Here is the example

```
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="helloWorld">
    <apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>Hello World</masterLabel>
    <targets>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
            <property name="string" type="String" default="jsMetaValue"></property>
            <property name="boolean" type="Boolean" default="true"></property>
            <property name="integer" type="Integer" default="5"></property>
            <property name="picklist" type="String" default="value3" datasource="value1,value2,value3" />
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: All are set as required, but I am not able to see lightning page under Login & Registration -> Login Page Type (Community Builder Page)

Comment: Did you get this solved? I am also facing this issue need you help. @Avijit

Comment: @karan - Unfortunately no.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to customize the login experience, then it seems that you need to [customize the standard Login community page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.externalidentityImplGuide.meta/externalidentityImplGuide/external_identity_create_branded_experience.htm) itself.

So try to add your custom LWC component on that std login page and under Administration settings, select login page type as Community Builder page and choose `login` .

Do read documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_customize_login_page.htm&type=5) about customizing apex logic for custom login behaviour.

From community builder, remember to publish your changes before testing the login.

Comment: Yes I get this, we cannot use `ShowToastEvent` `lightning/platformShowToastEvent` in `login` page that is why I was creating new Community Builder page. But the challenge is I am not able to select new page from page selection.

Comment: @Avijit as per component reference [lightning/platformShowToastEvent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-platform-show-toast-event/documentation) is available in lightning experience, it is not indicated as being supported in communities. so not sure you can use this in community pages

Comment: `ShowToastEvent` is supported if we create lightning community page, I have tested.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question but this is another way of configuring a custom login page.

Create a page variation of the standard Login Page as shown below. I gave the new page variation as **CustomLoginPage** and marked it as Default.

[image]

Now, you can edit the page and add/remove components from this page. You can even change page structure to 2 column layout and etc.

Here you can see that I removed the company logo and Already employee section and you can even drop your custom built components here.

[image]