# Has anyone implemented Community Registration/Login/Forgot Password with LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-community

Are there any examples that anyone can point me to that show how to implement Community self-registration/login/forgot password with Lightning Web Components?

Comment: You might find this useful: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/289282/16304